# Formik library's checkbox is not working in Microsoft Edge but working in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, formik

I am using one checkbox using the formik library's Field component this check box is working fine in chrome but not in microsoft edge,

I have cleared the cache along with browser history and also the Microsoft edge is up to date. what do I do?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  checkBoxSize: {
    transform: 'scale(1.4)',
  },
  checkBoxDiv: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(0.85),
  }
}))
```

```
const classes = useStyles()
```

```
   <Grid xs={1} className={classes.checkBoxDiv}>
                <Field
                  title="Update in Development Timeline"
                  type="checkbox"
                  name={`trainingGroups[${groupIndex}].trainings[${trainingIndex}].Is_centralize_duration`}
                  className={classes.checkBoxSize}
                />
              </Grid>
```